PAC-Learning, error estimation
I'm looking at this true/false question (currently in a ML course)
and there's no given solution/explanation for this, I cant really understand what am I supposed to look for when facing this:
"for some family of classifiers $H$, assuming it contains the perfect classifier, we are able to sample a group $S$ from distribution $D$ with enough samples such that the real error over the distribution $D$ is in range $\pm \epsilon$ for all $h\in H$, in a probability of our choosing."
what confuses me the most is the "probablility to our choosing"
because up to that part, the statement seems to be true.
